# onselect is not working in jquery datepicker in AdminLTE-master template

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

```
 $('#date_of_birth').datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
           yearRange:"-60:+0",

          onSelect: function (date) {
                  alert("dateofbirth");
                  var dob = new Date(date);
                  var today = new Date();
                  var age = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();   
                  $('.getage').val(age);
                }
          });
```

**onSelect** function is not working.I cant get the value of the date selected from the datepicker in **AdminLTE-master template** only.I can get the answer in some other template.

Comment: Pls ask the question clearly. What is that AdminLTE-master template ?

Comment: that is the template name i'm using

Answer (score 0):

AdminLTE template doesn't use jQuery Datepicker. It uses bootstrap datepicker.

Please have a look at bootstrap datepicker documentation: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/